# 301 redirect whithout append paramenter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

```
RedirectPermanent /forum-old-f48.html /forum-neu-f1.html
```

**301 Result:**

```
forum-neu-f1.html?f=48&start=
```

**Target:** Dont append the "?f=48&start=" part. How can I make a stop behind the html?

The result should look like this:

```
forum-neu-f1.html
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip off query string you need to use `mod_rewrite` rule. Have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum-old-f48\.html$ /forum-neu-f1.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

You should test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you very much anubhava. I will accept the answer in 6 minutes :)